# Where do I put my .js files?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, ssh, express, vps

I'm using ssh root to a VPS Ubuntu 10.04 server from Linode that has Node.JS, Express, MongoDB, etc. installed.

What I'm wondering is if I have a file called test-file.js with code:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();

// Configuration
app.configure( function() {
});

// Routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

How do I upload the file or make it work with the server?

Comment: http://library.linode.com/getting-started

Comment: http://library.linode.com/beginners-guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `scp` (secure copy) command to copy the file over to the linode box.

`scp path/to/test-file.js root@linodebox:/root`

Remember to replace `linodebox` with the ip address of your linode server.

This will put `test-file.js` in the `/root` directory and you can use `node test-file.js` to run the file. Grant that nodejs and express is installed correctly.

Comment: When I use scp path/to/test-copy.js linodebox:/root/ I get
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname linodebox: Name or service not known lost connection

If I take off linodebox, and do scp path/to/test-copy.js /root I get cp: cannot stat `path/to/test-copy.js': No such file or directory

Comment: Remember to replace linodebox with the ip address of your linode server. Please READ my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't see the root@linodebox. I did that and everything went through but then I got "path/to/test-copy.js: No such file or directory"

Comment: "path/to/test-copy.js" is where you test-copy.js file is located.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for this tutorial http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/run_nodejs_as_a_service_on_ubuntu_karmic/